# How to show that this seq. of r.v.-s $X_n=n 1_{\{[0, \frac{1}{n}\}}$ converge to $0$ a.s.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I want to find a counterexample about a sequence of r.v.-s converges a.s. but not in $L^1$. If we consider the r.v.-s $X_n=n 1_{\{[0, \frac{1}{n}\}}$. How to show that this seq. converge to $0$ a.s.?  My question is that how to show $\lim_n X_n(\omega)=0$ for $\omega \neq 0$?

I try to use the definition of limit that to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $|\omega-\omega_0|<\delta$,

$$
|X_n(\omega)-0|<\epsilon.
$$

However, $|X_n(\omega)-0|=n 1_{\{[0, \frac{1}{n}\}}$. How to bound it by $\epsilon$?

Comment: your definition of almost sure convergence does not make sense and is not the correct one

Comment: @operatorerror Sorry, how to prove it a.s.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of almost sure convergence of $X_n$ to $0$ is that
$$
P(\{ \omega:\lim_{n}X_n(\omega)=0\})=1.
$$
For $\omega\ne 0$, $\lim_nX_n(\omega)=0$, and $P(\{0\})=0$ (assuming $P$ is Lebesgue measure of course).

Comment: Yes, my question is that how to show $\lim_n X_n(\omega)=0$ for $\omega \neq 0$?

Comment: Let $\omega\ne 0$. Find $n$ large enough so that $\frac1n<\omega$....can you finish?

Comment: If choose $1/n <\omega$, how to show that $|X_n(\omega)|<\epsilon$? That is what I want to ask.

Comment: If $1/n<\omega$, $X_n(\omega)=0$.

Comment: Oh! I see, thanks!

Comment: But how to choose $\delta$ for $|\omega-\omega_0|<\delta$?

Comment: Why do you need $|\omega - \omega_0| < \delta$? You're not proving any kind of continuity/limit with respect to $\omega$, but with respect to $n$.

Comment: @quasAliki this is exactly what i meant by your definition not making sense. Are you getting confused with some kind of continuity statement?

Comment: @operatorerror It is clear now! Thanks.